# in each loop selected index of select element are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some select element in a page with css style set for them.I use this selector for select all them :

```
$('.Field3')
```

and with each loop I want to get selected index of them,but when I change one of them selected item I get selected index set for all.

I create a jsFiddle for it.please change a select element item and click on the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/uLvyS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this + "option:selected")
```

does not make much sense. In the function passed to `.each`, `this` is a jQuery object, not a string. You cannot magically turn a jQuery object into a selector.

What you want is `.find`, which finds descendants of the element(s) in the jQuery object: http://jsfiddle.net/uLvyS/1/.

```
$(this).find("option:selected")
```